# Terminal stops writing its output to the file if the file is changed

Tags: command-line, output

I have a running process that was started using

```
./process | tee -a output.txt
```

Since this is a rather long process, the output file is large and each time I open it to check, I have to wait for it to be loaded and then have to scroll down to the bottom, which is not convenient. Therefore, I decided to move the current content to a backup file `output_bak.txt` and leave the current `output.txt` blank so that it only contains new output. Unfortunately that did not work. The process does not write to `output.txt` anymore.

My question is how to let the process continue to write to `output.txt`?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update:** What I meant by 'moving the content' is actually copy the content of the file into another file, then delete the content in the current file. More precisely, what I did is: open `output.txt`, press Ctrl + A to copy the content then Ctrl + V in `output_bak.txt`, then back to `output.txt` and Ctrl + A then Delete and Save.

Comment: "move"? That will never work. You need to copy and use "> {file}" to empty the active one.

Comment: @Rinzwind What I did is: Ctrl + A to copy the content then Ctrl + V in the new file, then Ctrl + A again in the current file to delete the content and save the file. Unfortunately it's already done and I cannot revert it :(

Answer (score 3):

You can't. When you open a file, the process gets a file handle. The file handle does not change **even if the file is moved or removed**. Thus, the process will be writing to the same file handle, which you moved to `output_bak.txt`. You will have to close a file and reopen it.

You can use unix utilities like `tail` to view the end of the file. `tail -n 20 output.txt` will output the last 20 lines of `output.txt`.

Tail can also provide a live view. `tail -f output.txt` will show content as it is written to the file, in a continuous stream, until you interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

This is by the way how logrotate works. Move the file, create a new empty file, and restart the process writing to the log file.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did not move the file itself but only its content. Please see the update in the question.